# how to solve /bin/sh: protoc: command not found?

Tags: java, maven-3, protocol-buffers

I have installed protobuf 2.5.0  in my CentOs,

when i execute the command **protoc --version**, it yields

> **libprotoc 2.5.0**

as output.

but Once I have pulled code from git and when I try to compile it using Maven3, the proto module throws error saying,

> **protoc failed error: /bin/sh: protoc: command not found**

I refereed many blogs and also did try to change my bashrc path as follows,

> **export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_67**
>
> **export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin**
>
> **export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib**

but if I execute,

> **sudo yum install protobuf-compiler**

it installs protobuf2.3 compiler and this particular error gets solved. But since my pom file has protobuf 2.5.0, **java abstract method error** arises during the next compilation. I'm stuck on how to proceed. I've spend many hrs in it, so any help is much appreciated.

my pom file for the proto module,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>GradPower</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.screative.gardpower</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>proto</groupId>
    <artifactId>proto</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-protoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocExecutable>protoc</protocExecutable>
                    <protoSourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/proto/</protoSourceRoot>

                    <languageSpecifications>
                        <LanguageSpecification>
                            <language>JAVA</language>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/protoc
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </LanguageSpecification>
                    </languageSpecifications>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>dtrott</id>
            <url>http://maven.davidtrott.com/repository</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>



</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `protoc` should have never been installed in `/usr/local/lib`. If installing from source, it should've been installed into `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, answers do not belong inside questions -- editing them out is explicitly desirable per [meta]; see in particular [How best to deal with self-answers edited into questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402010/how-best-to-deal-with-self-answers-edited-into-questions)

Answer (score 0):

You should run 'sudo ldconfig' to finish the installation.

I guessed you set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add /usr/local/lib in your environment setting. And it doesn't take effect when building project with maven/sbt and other build tools.

Answer (score -3):

Answer extracted from the Question (written by OP):

> I solved it. I copied protoc file from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/bin`
>   and it solved it.

Comment: You're trying to claim the answer as your own! If you want to tidy up the question, inform the OP to answer their own question.

Comment: Or use the "Community Wiki" checkbox to disclaim reputation for something you didn't write. Mind, as long as credit is given doing this is within the rules, and I'm not contributing to downvoting it -- but flagging things where the content was someone else's as CW is considered good form.